# Where clause not working on LINQ IQueryable query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using Linq to Entities, the where clause is not working when I do a Where lamba expression on a Linq object created with a written LINQ statement.

This does not work.  Query executes, but results are returned unfiltered.

```
var myQuery = (from l in db.MyTable
                     select l);
myQuery.Where(r => availableStatusList.Contains(r.Status));
var myObj = myQuery.ToList();
```

This does work.  Query executes, AND results are returned filtered properly.

```
var myQuery = (from l in db.MyTable
                     select l).Where(r => availableStatusList.Contains(r.Status));
var myObj = myQuery.ToList();
```

As far as I understand, both of these should return equivalent results.  Any reason why the first one does not listen to the Where clause?

Comment: You didn't assign it back to myQuery. A `Where` clause creates a new object, it doesn't mutate an existing object.

Comment: Try putting the 'where' in the same original format (not mixing formats from standard to inline): from l in db.MyTable where availableStatusList.Contains(l.Status) select l;.  I'm curious to see if that changes it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `Where` clause does not create a new object when invoked; it applies a filter to an existing collection by wrapping the collection in a filter that will eventually be run.  However, since it is a pure function, the return value of that filter needs to be returned to the original reference `myQuery`, which is why the second example works...you have chained the result through the `Where()` clause back to `myQuery`.  You return the filtered collection back, materializing the deferred query with `ToList()`.

In the first example, you are assuming that the filter is applied directly to the collection, but that isn't how `LINQ` works, since the filter doesn't modify the collection immediately when the function is called. Rather, it only applies a predicate that WILL be applied provided it is "attached" to the original `Queryable` collection and you resolve the query with `ToList()`.

It is sometimes easier to think about deferred execution as a series of promises.

If I give you a dollar, you have a dollar.  If I take 25 cents for taxes, I've *immediately* resolved our transaction (query).

However, if I promise to give you a dollar on Tuesday, I've returned a `Queryable<T>` *promise*.

Multiple events could occur however between now and Tuesday.  I could chain a filter for taxes (25 cents), a filter for a stick of gum (25 cents), or any other filter.

However, our bookkeeping system has a caveat.  We can't just call `.Taxes()` (our `Where` clause) on the total promised amount and expect it to update.  We have to *record* our transaction against the promised amount by returning the filter to the original variable, updating it with the transaction that has occurred against our promised amount.

```
myQuery = myQuery.Where(condition);
```

On Tuesday, when you come to collect your payment (by calling `ToList()` on the series of chained promises/filters), I deduct what has occurred from what was promised, resulting in a 50 cent payout.  That's deferred execution at work.

Comment: I thought the 'Where' clause does in fact return a new ienumerable, filtered and such.  var list = new List<string>{"hi","bye"}; Assert.AreNotSame(list,list.Where(w=>w == "hi"));

Comment: @BlackjacketMack IEnumerable is NOT IQuerable.  Updated answer for emphasis.  In addition, your comparison is invalid.  Your comparing type of list to type of IEnumerable, which is invalid.  They are NOT the same type, although the underlying collection has not changed.  If we are talking "object" in terms of reference, yes a new reference is created.  If we are talking "object" in terms of underlying collection, no, a new collection is not created and returned until the query is materialized.

Comment: I see...so the IQueryable keeps getting modified but retains the same reference?  So if I were to add additional clauses the Assert.AreSame() would pass?  I was under the impression that, like IEnumerables, each appended linq clause would return a new and different IQueryable, affectively wrapping the previous statements as a decorator would.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack in the case of either IQueryable or IEnumerable, your impression is correct, it returns a newly wrapped series of statements that will be executed when resolved.  But my point is that the underlying collection is still the same.  It's just an issue of semantics.  Your understanding is correct.  My gripe was with the terminology.  It's still the original collection (object).  However, if you look at a series of chained where clauses, you'll find that the object only gets wrapped once, which is interesting.

Comment: ...ok interesting.  Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 10):

Shorter answer:

Similar to a string mutator function, you need to assign it back to the variable:

```
string sample = "text";

// this doesn't change sample
sample.ToUpper();   

// this one does
sample = sample.ToUpper();
```

So what you need is:

```
myQuery = myQuery.Where(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example

```
1.    var myQuery = (from l in db.MyTable select l);
2.    myQuery.Where(r => availableStatusList.Contains(r.Status));
3.    var myObj = myQuery.ToList();
```

Line 1 returns myQuery

Line 2 throws the result of the Where(..) clause away

lint 3 starts off from myQuery...

Potentially what you meant to write in example 1 is:

```
1.    var myQuery = (from l in db.MyTable select l);
2.    var q2 = myQuery.Where(r => availableStatusList.Contains(r.Status));
3.    var myObj = q2.ToList();
```

Where the result of the Where clause are kept in q2 and now the q2.ToList() of my interpretation of your intension is equivalent to your 2nd example's myQuery.ToList()