# C# deserialize json and find

Tags: c#, json, linq, object, json-deserialization

How could I find a specific id in this list?

```
var contactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);

contactList.contacts.FindAll(x => x.id == item.id);
```

The code above is not filtering by id and is returning all rows from object.

(Visual Studio is not showing me .Where clause only .Find and  .FindAll)

C# code

```
namespace RestDemo.Model 
{ 
   public class Phone 
   { 
      public string mobile { get; set; } 
      public string home { get; set; } 
      public string office { get; set; } 
   } 

   public class Contact 
   { 
      public int id { get; set; } 
      public string name { get; set; } 
      public string email { get; set; } 
      public string address { get; set; } 
      public string gender { get; set; } 
      public Phone phone { get; set; } 
   } 

   public class ContactList 
   { 
      public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; } 
   } 
}
```

Json:

```
{ "contacts": [     {           "id": 200,          "name": "Ravi Tamada",          "email": "ravi@gmail.com",          "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",            "gender": "male",           "phone": {              "mobile": "+91 0000000000",             "home": "00 000000",                "office": "00 000000"           }       },      {           "id": 201,          "name": "Klev Krist",           "email": "klev@gmail.com",          "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",            "gender": "male",           "phone": {              "mobile": "+91 0000000000",             "home": "00 000000",                "office": "00 000000"           }       },      {           "id": 202,          "name": "Paul Neil",            "email": "paul.neil@gmail.com",         "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",            "gender": "male",           "phone": {              "mobile": "+91 0000000000",             "home": "00 000000",                "office": "00 000000"           }       }   ]}
```

Thanks

Comment: How does your jsonString look like?

Comment: Show us `ContactList` class, what is in `contacts` and `jsonString`

Comment: You don't assign the results of `FindAll` anywhere. How do you know that filtering didn't work?

Comment: FindAll is not an "inplace" thing. It returns the filtered list . Store it somewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where clause not working on LINQ IQueryable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730649/where-clause-not-working-on-linq-iqueryable-query)

Comment: I know that FindAll is not a Linq Function but for this case it basically the same behavior

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FindAll method does not assign an object to the search result.

You have to keep the search result somewhere.

**Example Multi Result**

If you are expecting multiple results

```
var contactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
var findedContact = contactList.contacts.FindAll(x => x.id == item.id);
//You business codes..
```

**Example Single Result**

If you are only waiting for 1 result

```
var contactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
var oneContact = contactList.contacts.Find(x => x.id == item.id);
if(oneContact ==null){
    //not found business codes
}
else {
   //find result business codes
}
```

Comment: .Find() did not work for 1 result. It brings a couple of rows yet. I will use Linq instead. Thanks.

Comment: @user2250504 It is not mandatory to use linq. For this situation Find(single) or FindAll(multi). I said two answers in the answer.

Comment: Ok, In mocked tests Find() or Where() are working successfully. I will try to implement in oficial code later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find a certain id, we'll call it

```
var idToFind = "myID";
```

To find all contacts with said ID:

```
var contacts = contactList.contacts.Where(contact=> contact.id == idToFind);
```

To find at least one contact with said ID:

```
var contactWithID = contactList.contacts.FirstOrDefault(contact=> contact.id == idToFind);
// Before using, check if null, means no contact matched the id.
if(contactWithID != null)
{
   // A contact was found.
}
else
{
   // No contact matching that id is found.
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio is no showing .Where Claude only .Find or .FindAll

Comment: @user2250504 What error you are facing while writing `FirstOrDefault` or `Where`

Comment: @user2250504 Add using System.Linq at the top of your class file.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on @Tenretni's answer, I guess you missed to use `System.Linq` library in your code.

Import `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq` in your code and use `FirstOrDefault()` or `.Where()` clause

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

//…

string jsonString = @"{ 'contacts': [{ 'id': 'c200', 'name': 'Ravi Tamada', 'email': 'ravi@gmail.com', 'address': 'xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country', 'gender': 'male', 'phone': { 'mobile': '+91 0000000000', 'home': '00 000000', 'office': '00 000000' } }] }";

var contactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
var item = "c200";
var result = contactList.contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item);
Console.WriteLine(result.name);

//If you have multiple records with same ID then you can try where clause
var result = contactList.contacts.Where(x => x.id == item);      //Here result will be list of Contact
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6mg6vu)

Comment: In this case, searching by id can find more than 1 row. I can list many rows, but don't wanna list all rows.....

Comment: @user2250504 In that case you can use .Where() clause.

Comment: Yes, but I will add System.Linq reference... It was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to your case, I am using the same `Model` structure to deserialize your JSON and then use the `Where` linq clause to achieve what you require. A working fiddle can be found at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SAcFja

Code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ 'contacts': [{ 'id': 200, 'name': 'Ravi Tamada', 'email': 'ravi@gmail.com', 'address': 'xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country', 'gender': 'male', 'phone': { 'mobile': '+91 0000000000', 'home': '00 000000', 'office': '00 000000' } }] }";
        var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
        //Console.WriteLine(data.contacts);

        var found=data.contacts.Where(x=>x.id.ToString()=="200");

        foreach(var value in found)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(value.id);
          Console.WriteLine(value.address);     
        }       
    }
}

   public class Phone 
   { 
      public string mobile { get; set; } 
      public string home { get; set; } 
      public string office { get; set; } 
   } 

   public class Contact 
   { 
      public string id { get; set; } 
      public string name { get; set; } 
      public string email { get; set; } 
      public string address { get; set; } 
      public string gender { get; set; } 
      public Phone phone { get; set; } 
   } 

   public class ContactList 
   { 
      public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; } 
   }
```

Output when id=200:

```
200
xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country
```

Comment: Visual Studio is not showing me .Where() clause to filter object content... only .Find() or .FindAll()

Comment: @user2250504 You would have to import `System.Linq` in your project.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks.

Comment: @user2250504 What is your Framework version? You can check that by Going to Project -> Properties -> Application and check the Target Framework property. If your target framework is prior to 3.5 then `System.Linq` wont work since it was introduced on .NET Framework 3.5. More on this topic can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659934/visual-studio-does-not-recognize-system-linq

Comment: Version 4.7 Thanks

Comment: Okay, you might missing a reference then. You would need to add it explicity. I hope the link that I gave in my previous  comment helped you to resolve this.